# boost asio read dynamic size message

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

How to receive properly N bytes from socket using boost asio. I assumed that first 4 bytes are length of my message so I tried something like this:

```
            size_t len = 0;
            boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(&len, sizeof(size_t)));
            std::cout<<"READ SOMETHING: "<< len <<std::endl;
            boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(vec, len), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(len), error);
            std::cout<<"READ TO BUFFER END"<<std::endl;
```

I expected that second read calling will block until **len** of bytes will receive but i looks like it's not working like that.

My output looks like (2x int32 equals 4):

```
 READ SOMETHING: 4
 READ TO BUFFER END
 READ SOMETHING: 4
 READ TO BUFFER END
```

I tried to send 8 bytes once or 2x 4bytes and it looks doesn't work correctly.

Comment: How are you sending the bytes? Can you include a sscce?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `vec` might be too small.

The [documentation states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload24.html) (note the `min(...)`):

> #### Return Value
>
> A `mutable_buffers_1` value equivalent to:
>
> ```
> mutable_buffers_1(
>     data.size() ? &data[0] : 0,
>     min(data.size() * sizeof(PodType), max_size_in_bytes));
> ```

So, if you have

```
std::vector<char> vec(4);
```

and use it with

```
boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(vec, len), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(len), error);
```

the buffer will actually be only 4 bytes, not `len`. This combined with

> #### [`boost::asio::read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload3.html)
>
> ```
> template<
>     typename SyncReadStream,
>     typename MutableBufferSequence,
>     typename CompletionCondition>
> std::size_t read(
>     SyncReadStream & s,
>     const MutableBufferSequence & buffers,
>     CompletionCondition completion_condition);
> ```
>
> This function is used to read a certain number of bytes of data from a stream. The call will block until one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred is equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
> - The completion_condition function object returns 0.

It will return early due to the first end condition